# What are the supported image file formats for display on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an image in .jpg format.  Is that readable within an iPhone application?  What are all of the image file extensions that can be loaded natively within an iPhone application?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think many images file extension is readable in iPhone. Just name a few : jpg, jpeg, png

Here is the full list:

> Format | Filename extensions
>
> - Tagged Image File Format (TIFF)
> - Joint Photographic Experts Group (JPEG)
> - Graphic Interchange Format (GIF)
> - Portable Network Graphic (PNG)
> - Windows Bitmap Format (DIB)
> - Windows Icon Format (.ico)
> - Windows Cursor (.cur)
> - XWindow bitmap (.xbm)

[A list is from here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/LoadingImages/LoadingImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH17-SW7)

Comment: Apple just moved the documentation around. The table of supported formats is now here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/LoadingImages/LoadingImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH17-SW7

Answer (score 11):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/LoadingImages/LoadingImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH17-SW7

see Supported Image Formats

Doc says that:

> Generally, the image formats that UIKit supports are the same formats supported by the Image I/O framework.

And in [I/O Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_basics/ikpg_basics.html) docs said that:

> The Image I/O framework understands most of the common image file formats, such as JPEG, JPEG2000, RAW, TIFF, BMP, and PNG. Not all formats are supported on each platform. For the most up-to-date list of what Image I/O supports, you can call the these functions:
>
> `CGImageSourceCopyTypeIdentifiers` returns an array of the Uniform Type Identifiers (UTIs) that Image I/O supports as image sources.
>
> `CGImageDestinationCopyTypeIdentifiers` returns an array of the uniform type identifiers (UTIs) that Image I/O supports as image destinations.

Comment: @Flimm, looks like apple updated their api docs since 2010, now you can check that table here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/LoadingImages/LoadingImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH17-SW7